# Symfony2: How to render nested foreach loops and limit the inner loop to create an image gallery?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I have a nested loop and then carry on from the previous loop?

Example:

```
{% for image in site_images[page.id].images %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
        <img src="{{ image[loop.index0] }}" />
    </div>
</div>
....
{% endfor %}
```

How can I make it show 4 images in the first `.container > .item div`, then come out create a new `.container > .item div` and carry on so it would be `image[4]`

Comment: I am note quite sure what you want to accomplish. Can you elaborate?
site_images[page.id].images is an 2d array, isn't it? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: do you mean in the case of image number 4 in array create a new container

Comment: I want to show 4 images per div container. `image` contains an array of image paths. At the moment I'm getting the div container followed by **all** the images in the array. I need just 4 then create a new container with another 4 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html)** filter:

```
{% for section in images|batch(4) %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">

            {% for image in section %}
                <img src="{{ image }}" />
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's doing exactly what I want. The only problem now is the loop.index0 is resetting every new container. Is there a way to keep incrementing?

Comment: I got around this by setting a variable and then increment it in the loop.

Comment: I know this is quite an old entry but slice is a better option as documented here https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-a-subset